# knock.exe crashes Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

Before you decide that this is an off-topic question in this site, please consider that I'm talking about my Windows 10 dev computer trying to run "knock.exe ..." command for our own Git server. So this is obviously a programming-related question.

When I run the command in my Windows 10 command prompt, the PC just stops responding and the only way to resolve this is to reboot the PC.
My PC is running a local dev machine (Debian VM via Orable VirtualBox) and we have our own Git server.

Is there a way to fix the file itself or run something else?

UPDATE:

Additional information, according to questions in the comments here:

My PC is running Windows 10 as the OS and a Debian virtual machine (implemented via Oracle's VirtualBox). I'm not 100% sure that this has got anything to do with the problem described in this question, just saw it fit to provide this information too.

When I say that PC stops responding, I mean that nothing responds in any of the running programs and rebooting it is done by physically pressing the "off" button of the computer.

Our Git server in the company is external of our network, therefore in order to maintain security, we use "knock" in order to make a connection between the office network (our local dev machines) and the remote Git server.

Comment: I think this is typo not gif but git and Oracle. In addition this is offtopic due to typos xD (joking little)

Comment: I have three questions: **1.** I don't know `knock.exe`. What is it? **2.** What do you mean with "stops responding" since you can reboot the PC? Or do you reset it (without shutdown)? **3.** I'm not quite sure about your setup. Are you running Windows 10 as host and Debian as client or the other way arount?

Comment: Questions like these need to documented the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: check your RAM and other settings in your VM maybe set to big and PC not keep up and if it doesn't keep up, reduce params maybe VM is overloaded